# how to deploy a web app that uses google speech api

Tags: node.js, speech-recognition, putty, digital-ocean, google-speech-api

I've managed to create a web app that uses google speech api

It's essentially a video chat web app that translates text real time

So speech is converted to text, which is then translated to another language(using google translate api) and the translated text is exchanged between users

My program is written in nodejs

In my program, I have used arecord to record speech that is to be sent to the google speech api

So far, I have deployed the web app in a Digital Ocean VPS and use putty to run and terminate the program. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RE2PLyFqCzE) tutorial to get so far.I managed to get the video chat bit to work on deployment, however when the speech api part of the program runs, I get an error saying "spawn arecord ENOENT". This could be because I'm running the program on putty and so it can't find a program called "arecord"

How do I go about resolving this?

Please let me know if you need to see the code and I will edit my question to include it.

Comment: Time to understand that remote software does not have access to your microphone.

Comment: Alright. What can I do then to get google speech api to work on deployment?

Comment: You put code there and it works, there should be no problem. In your case microphone recording is broken, not google speech api.

Comment: Alright. But arecord works fine on localhost. So is there some configuration changes I need to make to get it to work with a remote host?